Can a Brahmana be a King?
I have heard that a brahmana cannot be coronated..Is it true? Are there any examples of Brahmin Kings in Dvapara or Treta yuga?

There is some conflicting info on this, but generally a Brahmin is prohibited from the King ceremony ritual

Can you cite sources?

I believe it is manu lemme see.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43199/is-yamunacharya-correct-in-stating-that-brahmins-cannot-be-crowned-kings

Nvm it was by a Vishistadvaitan

Oh, also, the mahabharata tag does not apply to most of these questions. Could you use the [scripture] tag when you're unsure what specific tags to use?
